# Use of Leaflet plugins in 'Leaflet for R' to connect with ArcGIS online

Tags: leaflet, r, arcgis-online, esri-leaflet

I was wondering if it is possible to use the plugins for the normal (non-R) version of Leaflet, and if, how I can do that.
reason I need to do that is, that some of the data I need to show are hosted at ArcGIS Online.

Currently available plugins via leaflet.com are 'leaflet-providers' and 'Esri Leaflet'

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding your exact question, but it is certainly possible to mix and match [esri-leaflet](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/) with other leaflet plugins.

you can find an example that mashes up with Leaflet.Elevation here:

http://johngravois.com/esri-leaflet-gp/elevation.html
https://github.com/jgravois/esri-leaflet-gp/blob/master/elevation.html

edit 5/1/2016:
it appears that the [Leaflet for R](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/tree/master/inst/htmlwidgets/plugins) project needs to include an explicit reference to any individual plugin you'd like to leverage in that environment. because it looks as if development of this project has slowed, i'm a little hesitant to take the time to propose another integration myself (because there are already a few [Pull Requests](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pulls) sitting idle).

that said, feel free to either file an issue in that project and cc/ [@jgravois](https://github.com/jgravois) if you'd like the maintainers to consider providing support, or if you're feeling more ambitious, you can also fork the project and take a stab at integrating our plugin yourself.  i'd be happy to try and help if you get stuck.

Comment: Yes, the question doesn't aim to mash-up leaflet plugins, but to use leaflet plugins in 'Leaflet for R'.

Comment: great sample of invoking our plugin from JS in shiny here: https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92